# TIFF Compression - Fax3SetupState: Bits/sample must be 1 for Group 3/4 encoding/decoding

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert PDF's to compressed TIFF files. Everything looks to be working, but I can't seem to get the group4 compression to work. My code is below:

```
from fitz.fitz import Colorspace
from PIL import Image

mat = fitz.Matrix(300 / 72, 300 / 72)  # sets zoom factor for 300 dpi
doc = fitz.open("/home/Image Conversion/test-pdf")

page_count = doc.pageCount

for page in range(0, page_count):
    print(page)
    page_load = doc.loadPage(page)
    pix = page_load.get_pixmap(matrix=mat)
    img_filename = "/home/Image Conversion/"+ "page_b_w-%04i.tiff" % page_load.number
    pix.pil_save(img_filename, format="TIFF", dpi=(300,300), compression="group4")
```

When running this code (With libtiff installed) I get the below error:

```
Fax3SetupState: Bits/sample must be 1 for Group 3/4 encoding/decoding.
```

I have tried resolving this by setting the colorspace to GRAY and converting to black and white, to no avail:

```
image_file.convert('1') # convert image to black and white
```

Comment: How, exactly, did you attempt to use `image_file.convert('1')`?  That's referring to a variable that doesn't exist in the code you posted, so the answer isn't obvious.

Comment: Hi Jason,

I used this to open the TIFF from the code above (without compression):
image_file = Image.open("/home/Image Conversion/page-0005.tiff")
I then used the below to save the converted b/w image:
image_file.convert('1') # convert image to black and white
image_file.save('/home/Image Conversion/page-0005_bw.tiff')

I then used doc = fitz.open("/home/Image Conversion/page-0005_bw.tiff") and went through the same code as above, trying to set compression=group4 but ran into the same issue.

Comment: So you didn't assign the result of `image_file.convert('1')` to a variable, or otherwise make any use of it?  That makes the conversion pointless.

Comment: Hi Jason,

I save it to file and then read it back in inside the next part of the code that does the compression, as I'm not sure I can save it to a variable and pass it to fitz.open(). I believe that needs a filepath.

Comment: `.convert()` *produces a new image object*.  You have to save THAT to the file, not `image_file`.

Comment: Thanks Jason,

I ended up resolving the issue with the following line:

image_file.save("/home/Image Conversion/page-0005_bw_COMPRESSION.tiff", compression="group4", dpi=(300,300))

This gives me the compressed output I need without having to send the output back to fitz.